# Even when a string (s1) contains 1 character, s1.Substring(1) returns an Empty string ("") - instead of IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am using C# 11.0, and saw some weird behavior, that I had never seen before. But I am sure the behavior is not because of the C# version that I am using.
Following is the explanation of the behavior I am seeing (the code):

```
char a1='a';
string s1=char.ToString(a1);
string s2 = s1.Substring(1);
```

After the code executes, `s2` is giving me the value of `string.Empty` (that is `""`). This is weird because, `s1` has only 1 character and, `s1.Substring(1)` should give `IndexOutOfRangeException`. This is because, the definition of Substring is `Substring(int startIndex)`. And `s1.Substring(1)` lies outside the bounds of `s1` (like most languages, a `string` starts from the 0th index in C#).

I also tried it in the immediate window, and following is the result that I got:

```
s1
"a"
s1[0]
97 'a'
s1[1]
's1[1]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233080
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
    Source: "System.Private.CoreLib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()\r\n   at System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index)"
    TargetSite: {Void ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()}
s1.Substring(0)
"a"
s1.Substring(1)
""
```

Though `s1.Substring(2)` correctly gives `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. But, I am perplexed to see why `s1.Substring(1)` returns an `Empty` string (that is `""`).
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

FYI - the answer I upvoted is explicit and makes more sense to the question I asked. Namely: [**[Returns] A string that is equivalent to the substring that begins at startIndex in this instance, or Empty if startIndex is equal to the length of this instance.**]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Surprising Substring behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704974/surprising-substring-behavior)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906320/unexpected-behavior-of-substring-in-c-sharp

Comment: @gunr2171, thanks for referring me to the questions. But the answer here is explicit and answers my question to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is actually explicitly documented in [`SubString`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) (added my won bolding for emphasis):

> [Returns] A string that is equivalent to the substring that begins at `startIndex` in this instance, or **Empty if `startIndex` is equal to the length of this instance**.